# How to run subroutines in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

While I recognize that this may be a trivial question, I have been having a tough time finding an answer in my research on the topic.

Let's say that I have a function, `statistics` that contains a variety of sub-routines, and that I put them in a cell at the top of my Jupyter Notebook.

How would I reference some of those sub-routines later on in a Jupyter Notebook?  Let's say that I want to use the `linearRegression` sub-routinethat I created an algorithm for in my `statistics` function.

I am receiving the error, `module 'statistics' has no attribute 'lienarRegression'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I understand, you have a function that has functions defined inside of it and want to use these sub-functions elsewhere? You cannot do that in Python. Define the sub-functions outside the main function and it should work fine.

So, go from this:

```
def Foo():
    def Bar():
        print("Hello world!")
    Bar()
```

to this:

```
def Bar():
    print("Hello world!")

def Foo():
    Bar()
```